# SVM performance not consistent with AUC score

Tags: r, svm, prediction, auc, e1071

I have a dataset that contains information about patients. It includes several variables and their clinical status (0 if they are healthy, 1 if they are sick).
I have tried to implement an SVM model to predict patient status based on these variables.

```
library(e1071)

Index <- 
  order(Ytrain, decreasing = FALSE)

SVMfit_Var <- 
  svm(Xtrain[Index, ], Ytrain[Index],
      type = "C-classification", gamma = 0.005, probability = TRUE, cost = 0.001, epsilon = 0.1)


preds1 <- 
  predict(SVMfit_Var, Xtest, probability = TRUE)
preds1 <- 
  attr(preds1, "probabilities")[,1]

samples <- !is.na(Ytest)
  pred <- prediction(preds1[samples],Ytest[samples])
  AUC<-performance(pred,"auc")@y.values[[1]]


prediction <- predict(SVMfit_Var, Xtest)
xtab <- table(Ytest, prediction)
```

To test the performance of the model, I have calculated the ROC AUC, and with the validation set I obtain an AUC = 0.997.
But when I view the predictions, all the patients have been assigned as healthy.

```
AUC = 0.997
> xtab
     prediction
Ytest  0  1
    0 72  0
    1 52  0
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the probabilities versus the fitted values? [You can read about how *probability* works with SVM here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302567/why-is-it-wrong-to-interpret-svm-as-classification-probabilities).

If you want to look at the performance you can use the library `DescTools` and the function `Conf` or with the library `caret` and the function `confusionMatrix`. (They provide the same output.)

```
library(DescTools)
library(caret)

# for the training performance with DescTools
Conf(table(SVMfit_Var$fitted, Ytrain[Index])) 
       # svm.model$fitted, y-values for training

# training performance with caret
confusionMatrix(SVMfit_Var$fitted, as.factor(Ytrain[Index])) 
             # svm.model$fitted, y-values 
                       # if y.values aren't factors, use as.factor()

# for testing performance with DescTools
    # with `table()` in your question, you must flip the order:
         # predicted first, then actual values
Conf(table(prediction, Ytest))

# and for caret
confusionMatrix(prediction, as.factor(Ytest))
```

Your question isn't reproducible, so I went through this with `iris` data. The probability was the same for every observation. I included this, so you can see this with another data set.

```
library(e1071)
library(ROCR)
library(caret)

data("iris")

# make it binary
df1 <- iris %>% filter(Species != "setosa") %>% droplevels()
# check the subset
summary(df1)

set.seed(395) # keep the sample repeatable
tr <- sample(1:nrow(df1), size = 70, # 70%
             replace = F)

# create the model
svm.fit <- svm(df1[tr, -5], df1[tr, ]$Species,
               type = "C-classification",
               gamma = .005, probability = T,
               cost = .001, epsilon = .1)

# look at probabilities
pb.fit <- predict(svm.fit, df1[-tr, -5], probability = T) 
            # this shows EVERY row has the same outcome probability distro
pb.fit <- attr(pb.fit, "probabilities")[,1]

# look at performance 
performance(prediction(pb.fit, df1[-tr, ]$Species), "auc")@y.values[[1]]
# [1] 0.03555556  that's abysmal!! 

# test the model
p.fit = predict(svm.fit, df1[-tr, -5])
confusionMatrix(p.fit, df1[-tr, ]$Species)
# 93% accuracy with NIR at 50%... the AUC score was not useful

# check the trained model performance
confusionMatrix(svm.fit$fitted, df1[tr, ]$Species)
# 87%, with NIR at 50%... that's really good
```